# What tags distinguish questions troubleshooting Drupal as a system?

Tags: discussion

(Sorry for the long post)

What tags are useful to distinguish Drupal platform questions? What are some good tags to address a question towards debugging which I can use to distinguish from individual module questions? Far from suggesting unspecific questions, I want to avoid generating advise directing me back to a road I've already covered. While every Drupal problem is reducible in part to a module, some problems may simply be uncommon or complex enough to not be recognized and need a different troubleshooting approach. What are some good tag combinations for posting questions on how the Druapl platform works? A specific problem with a general answer I think would help me gather information to write a more *relevant* question.

---

**For example.** 
Here's an example of a general question from StackExchange: [Which Drupal tables are safe to manually clear using phpmyadmin?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22041/which-drupal-tables-are-safe-to-manually-clear-using-phpmyadmin) Of course this question is tagged appropriately, Drupal version number and the generic database tag. But suppose for a moment the person with this problem, a huge database file, didn't know about phpmyadmin, and didn't know the size of the database was huge. Imagine they asked a question about the Migrate module using the Migrate tag (which has a total of 17 posts). Its very possible the module tag would abstract the problem to prevent a proper assessment. I use this only as an analogy.

---

**Of course my question started with a question.**
An unanswered specific problem I asked has [run into a wall](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26185/drupal-7-multi-site-install-is-half-working-whats-the-next-thing-to-check-with). Far from trying to advertise my problem, it raised the issue to prompt this missive.

I'll summarize briefly. This problem is a View that reports a database error, specifically with Draggableviews on a multisite installation. What's worse, in the three sites on my multisite I've created three new test cases of Draggableviews (in addition to the original content problem). Each essentially identical (not dentical content, but structurally). Each installation identical in its currently enabled modules and used themes. However, for one site DgVs works, for another site DgVs works with a notice and the last and same site as the original error faults with a database error. It won't display content or save changes in Views. While the final culprit points to Draggableviews, the fact that it works in my install at all points to some other problem with my installation. And specifically one of the three installations. Its just the type of question that needs to be debugged from another angle. But I don't know where to start.

Comment: May you remove the not relevant parts, and make the question more specific? So far, the only question I read is, "What tags are useful to distinguish Drupal platform questions?"

Comment: My post is in part a discussion, so if you would like to help please have patience with my ignorance. I'm trying my best. I've rewritten the question to describe what I _think_ I want, I've given an example, and I've summarized a post which is the specific cause for posting this discussion. As I see it, the original problem has too many variables, yet I've reached the limit of what I know to do in troubleshooting. My post is meant to help me write better questions (^_^)